# Repeating a monadic computation multiple times and printing out results? (MonadRandom)

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Right now I'm using the MonadRandom library.  I have a computation:

```
metroChain :: (RandomGen g) => Rand g Double
```

I'd like to perform it multiple times, and sequentially print out the results.
Or rather, I'd like to create some kind of list of multiple computations.

To do it once, I would use

```
main = do
  result <- evalRandIO metroChain
  print result
```

or

```
main = evalRandIO metroChain >>= (\result -> print result)
```

However, I'm having a lot of trouble being able to print out an arbitrary (n) amount of `metroChain` results.

Each result should use the RandomGen given by the end of the last result...that's how MonadRandom is supposed to work, right?

I've looked into `replicateM`, `fmap`, and a bit into transformers (although i admit I can't seem to understand them enough to grasp their application to my problem).

Can anyone help me achieve the functionality I'm looking for?  I feel like I'm missing something really simple.  But I'm pretty new to Haskell.

Comment: Did you try `replicateM_`?

Comment: n.b. `(\result -> print result)` is a complicated way of saying `print`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replicateM` is what you want in building up the random computation. (Unless tel's guess is correct.)

```
foo :: Int -> IO ()
foo n = do
    results <- evalRandIO (replicateM n metroStep)
    mapM_ print results
```

Then you want `mapM_` to aid in actually printing out the results.

Does this do what you want? Is there any of this you'd like me to expand on?

Comment: This does exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to make a leap and assume that `metroStep` is a MCMC Metropolis-Hastings iteration.

The problem you have is that you want the MH steps to be Markovian, but simply sharing `RandomGen` state, which is exactly what `replicateM n metroStep` does, is insufficient. That only makes it so that each step is capable of being based on independent random variables. To compare, if the `RandomGen` state weren't shared then immutability would guarantee that every `metroStep` is identical.

So what you really need is something that has both `RandomGen` state in order to provide an chain of psuedorandom numbers for generating independent variable samples *and* a fixed state so that at each step you can have `P(x_i | theta, x_(i-1))`. We build a transformer stack to do this—I'll use the `mtl` library and `random-fu` because I just wrote an MCMC using those libraries a few days ago.

```
metroStep :: (MonadRandom m, MonadState StateSpace m) => m StateSpace
```

where `StateSpace` is a point in state space including both observed an unobserved variables—it's every parameter on the right side of your likelihood function. Now, `replicateM n metroStep :: (MonadRandom m, MonadState StateSpace m) => m [StateSpace]` is a list of Markov-sequential `StateSpace` points.

Then we "run" a concrete version of this monad stack like this

```
do steps <- (`runRVar` StdRandom) . (`evalStateT` ss0) $ (replicateM n metroStep)
   mapM_ print steps
```

Comment: `metroStep` is actually badly named, it's n iterations of the metropolis algorithm.  In my actual code it's `metroChain n`.   I already have a way of making a metroChain from a number of individual steps?

Comment: Should I switch to completley using mtl/statespace?

This is my current "complete" code -- https://gist.github.com/mstk/5569453

Should I refactor this?

Comment: Your metroChain is basically replicateM applied to the state monad, discarding results. You can use combinations of print, mapM and replicateM atop it though to get your result.

Comment: I added a comment to that gist with a refactoring through `mtl`.